# How do I know if a Grails model was changed since its retrieval?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I want multiple users to be able to edit models in a web browser at the same time and conflicts detected when the save (so that the first user to write doesn't have their changes overwritten without the second user explicitly saying so). Here's the example:

User A retrieves object X and is looking at it in their browser.

Then User B retrieves object X, looks at it in their browser, modifies it, and saves it causing a post to the REST api in Grails and a `save` on the model to the database.

Then User A modifies and saves the object.

I want the application to detect that object X has been modified since user A retrieved it and I'll display a suitable message to user A with some options.

How do I know if the model has changed? Note that `isDirty` will not work and `save(flush:true)` will not work.

**UPDATE**

I see a couple answers that talk about Optimistic Locking and detecting a model change since it was *submitted*. I want to detect a change since it was *retrieved* by the user. Please read the question again.

Here I will clarify why Optimistic Locking will not solve the problem described above. However, I can imagine that there may be a way for me to use Optimistic Locking, but as it is described in the answers below and as it is described in the documentation, it will not help.  Here's why.

Optimistic Locking works within the request, not across requests. If a second user updates an object while an update request is in progress from the first user, then optimistic locking will only allow one user to perform the update. Optimistic Locking protects against a read-modify-write being interleaved with another read-modify-write in the *same* request. Here's a time line (where time is top to bottom) of the events that optimistic locking protects against:

```
User 1                          User 2
presses submit                  presses submit
in update action
|   read model
|                               in update action
|                               |   read model
|                               |   modify model
|                               |   write model
|                               return
|   modify model
|   write model - FAILS
return error or something
```

Writing the model by the first users post fails because the optimistic locking check detects the record was modified since it was read.

What I would like to protect against is the following timeline:

```
User 1                          User 2
visits web app                  visits web app
clicks link to edit model       clicks link to edit model
in edit action
|   read model
|   render model
return
                                in edit action
                                |   read model
                                |   render model
                                return
user edits model                user edits model
user thinks... hmm...           user submits
                                in update action
                                |   read model
                                |   modify model from params
                                |   write model
                                return
user submits
in update action
|   read model
|   modify model from params
|   write model - OOPS! overwrote previous changes
return
```

From this example you can see that User 1 overwrites User 2's changes. But User 1 made her changes based on an old copy of the model from the database and perhaps would have done something different if she had seen User 2's changes that happened while she was thinking.

Answer (score 2):

Optimistic locking is built in, as dmahapatro has said.  I would just add that Grails scaffolding takes this into account on the update actions for controllers.  As an example, note that it checks the version to see if Book has already been updated since it was submitted.

```
def update(Long id, Long version) {
        def bookInstance = Book.get(id)
        if (!bookInstance) {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'book.label', default: 'Book'), id])
            redirect(action: "list")
            return
        }

        if (version != null) {
            if (bookInstance.version > version) {
                bookInstance.errors.rejectValue("version", "default.optimistic.locking.failure",
                          [message(code: 'book.label', default: 'Book')] as Object[],
                          "Another user has updated this Book while you were editing")
                render(view: "edit", model: [bookInstance: bookInstance])
                return
            }
        }

        bookInstance.properties = params

        if (!bookInstance.save(flush: true)) {
            render(view: "edit", model: [bookInstance: bookInstance])
            return
        }

        flash.message = message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'book.label', default: 'Book'), bookInstance.id])
        redirect(action: "show", id: bookInstance.id)
    }
```

Comment: This. You have to check for the version change yourself. Its something that should be built in to all objects that have a version IMO.

Comment: Where is the `update` method called? Where is the `version` argument set? If it is set from the database when the request begins, then this will not work. If it is set from the object that the user submitted and has the value from when the user made his original request to start editing the object, then this should work.

Comment: version is in a hidden field on the edit.gsp (or whatever you might call it).  So when the form is submitted, it sends that version # in the request.  That version is then compared to the current db's version to determine if they are the same or not.  There's no "this should work".  It does work.

Comment: @Gregg, what if I am implementing Rest endpoints and not using HTML forms, and I insist on the "version" property being part of the request body and not part of the URL? I've found "bookInstance.properties=params" will not copy over the version property, nor will "bindData(dst, params)" do so. How can I retrieve the version property from the request body and still later process the request body's InputStream to bind my other properties? The InputStream can only be read once. Furthermore, to Jason's point, I thought this version checking was built-in without the need to manually write the code.

Comment: def version = params.version.  This also happens with transient properties. They don't auto-bind. Once you've pulled the version out of the request params, you can do whatever you want with it to compare.

Comment: @Gregg, I tried "params.version" and it does not contain the "version" property which I am including in the request body. All the params map has for me are properties in the URL query string and properties that I created in my UrlMappings.groovy. My request body looks something like: `{ "version": 10, "foo": "bar" }`

Answer (score 1):

Why do you feel `save(flush: true)` won't work? Don't you want to use it or you think of something else?

You must have read about [Optimistic Locking](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#locking) which works during `save(flush: true)`.
`version` the domain class X so that the version gets updated on a successful save(with flush).

On dirty update, app would throw `OptimisticLockingFailureException` as shown:

```
def airport = Airport.get(10)
try {
    airport.name = "Heathrow"
    airport.save(flush: true)
}
catch (org.springframework.dao.OptimisticLockingFailureException e) {
    // deal with exception
}
```

If you do not want to handle the exception as shown above, then before editing the domain for User A, try to [refresh](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/refresh.html) it and then update the info, in order to get the latest version of Object X. However, this route is inadvisable for long running sessions.

Comment: Optimistic locking only detects conflicts within a request. I'm looking to detect conflicts across requests. See my updated question.

Comment: Revisit Optimistic Locking again. It works and updates the version every time hibernate updates the row in database (when flushed). It does not matter if User is thinking or singing or hibernating before or after the update. :-) @Jason