# grails 2.4.2 optimistic locking seems not to work

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a few grails apps, that all currently running under grails 2.4.2.

In every of these apps, it seems, that the optimistic-locking feature is not working.

I have my domain classes and generated controllers. 
I use 2 different browsers (opera and firefox) for the tests and open the same domain-instance in both of the browsers.

In both edit-dialogs, I updated the fields to different values and save then the record in one of the browsers and afterwards in the other one.

My problem is, that I don't get a hint of the concurrent update which has taken place.
(Because the version-no from the original record is passed around in the views etc.)

Do I have to do the check for the version-no by myself? I thought, that would be handled by hibernate? (optimistic locking through the version field is default in grails...)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you have to check it by yourself. You can take a look at scaffolded views for the reference. 
Read this answer for the details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24051451/4769188